# Inline style React components not working

Tags: jss

Is there any way to use inline style for the JSS React components?
I have tried:

```
const inlineStyle = { width: '100%' }
const Example = () =>
    <Image style={ inlineStyle } />
```

But the style seems to be ignored. The output is:

```
<img />
```

Expected:

```
<img style="width: 100%"/>
```

I have read the release notes but cant se anything about ignoring styles.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a bug. I've logged an issue and it will be fixed for the upcoming GA release.